# A basic question about voltage current relation for an inductor

Tags: inductor

Section below is taken from a text:

[image]

[image]

What does the author try to explain here? What is that to do with integration that sudden change is not possible? Why infinite voltage would be needed for a sudden change?

I think I lost the link between the meaning of integration and its manifestation in an inductor. Can it be put in a better way to explain what the author means here?

edit:

[image]

Comment: Because integration means summation over time of an infinitesimally small quantity \$v\cdot dt\$

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288380/energy-stored-and-lagging-of-current-in-a-inductive-circuit/288384#288384

Comment: I see the new addition to your question. Your problem here is improper use of the simulator. Check the "skip initial operating point solution" checkbox (right-click your .tran card.) Fix that and you'll be fine in simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eugene's comment is a compact statement of just how I was thinking when I read your question. His writing of it "sings" in my mind like a melody I know well. But it probably could use some elaboration for you.

Perhaps it is simpler to start with this simple statement in algebra:

$$I_L=\frac{V_L}{L}\cdot t$$

The above would assume that at the start of the period of time the current in the inductor was zero. It also assumes that either \$V_L\$ is a constant, or else that it is the effective average value if it varied somehow during the indicated period of time. But I think you can see that this statement strongly states that it requires time. Zero time would mean zero current, here. So at its root you can see that it takes time. But this does not discuss the question you ask, which is about "sudden" changes. This is where calculus (which is no more than algebra, modified to add a new kind of special variable that can only hold infinitely small, but still non-zero, values -- those special variables noted by placing \$\textrm{d}\$ in front of them.)

The above expression is more exactly written this way (there are still more exact ways of writing it, that I'll avoid here):

$$\textrm{d}I_L=\frac{V_{L}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t$$

It's still the same thing as before except that I've replaced the finite variable \$t\$, which can only hold finite values, with the infinitesimal variable \$\textrm{d}t\$, which can only hold infinitesimal but non-zero values. (Obviously, the factor \$\frac{V_L}{L}\$ remains a ratio of finite values.) The product of a finite ratio, times an infinitesimally small value, must itself be infinitesimally small. So the left side reflects this fact by replacing the earlier finite variable with its infinitesimal equivalent.

But let's look at this latest equation, now. What does it *say*? It says that in order to make even the smallest, most infinitesimally small change in the current of the inductor, you must apply a non-zero voltage for at least an infinitesimally small period of time.

In short, it takes time (and a non-zero applied voltage) to make a change in the current. I don't even need the integral to say so.

So why is the integral added? Because infinitesimally small values are pretty much useless for engineers making stuff. They need finite values, not infinitely small ones. So how many of these tiny values are needed to make a finite value? An infinite number of them, of course. So the special integral sign was invented.

Keeping in mind that whatever you do to one side of an equation you have to also do to the other side:

$$\begin{align*}
\textrm{d}I_L&=\frac{V_{L}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t\\\\
\int \textrm{d}I_L&=\int \frac{V_{L}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t\\\\
I_L&=\int \frac{V_{L}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t
\end{align*}$$

The last step, looking at the left side change, is true because if you sum of an infinite number of infinitely small pieces of X, you get X. Obviously. If you divide up anything into an infinite number of tiny bits, then pasting all those bits back together must be what you originally started out with. So this last step is a "no brainer" in calculus.

Since \$L\$ is often taken as constant, then it should be obvious that I can treat \$\frac{V_{L_1}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t+\frac{V_{L_2}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t+\frac{V_{L_3}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t+ ...\$ by extracting the \$\frac{1}{L}\$ part and performing the sum without it, first, applying that fraction later. So:

$$\begin{align*}
I_L&=\frac{1}{L}\int V_{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t
\end{align*}$$

A person familiar with calculus will just see the above immediately as the same as:

$$\textrm{d}I_L=\frac{V_{L}}{L}\cdot \textrm{d}t$$

So when the writer wrote as they did, they were seeing the core I started with above -- which is that to make a change in the current you must make a change in the time. So "it takes time for current to change." So from the integral, the differential obviously follows, and from the differential the conclusion then follows. That's how one gets there from here, I suppose.

You asked:

> What is that to do with integration that sudden change is not
>   possible?

So in a very meaningful sense, it has nothing at all to do with the integration. Instead, it has to do with the differential equation that results when you mentally strip the integral away from it.

---

I'm sorry for elaborating so much on this. But I want to point out that there is a thinking process that you really need to struggle with yourself to acquire. It is crucial, as it influences your very ability to actually "see." You are blind before and have vision after. It's that much of "night and day." And it changes the way you see everything around you.

Comment: I don't get your first equation. If IL = (VL/L)*t, IL would increase linearly by time t. But when I simulate a circuit see my edit, the current is constant. Please see my edit.

Comment: or check out here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTPTy.png

Comment: @newage2000 That's because you didn't check the "skip initial operating point solution" checkbox. Fix that and you'll be fine in simulation.

Comment: Oh you are right. It is how you say now in the simulator, the current keeps increasing. But they named it "skip initial operating point solution" is a bit weird to me. By clicking that we are not skipping any detail we are actually adding some details. What does this actually do that we get completely different plots?

Comment: @newage2000 A Spice transient analysis is normally preceded by computing the voltage and current values of its branch-constitutive equations for all capacitors and inductors. Adding UIC tells Spice to just skip all that and use zeros. Did you see how large your fixed value was?

Comment: Do you mean if I chose skip all the initial parameters in the case the inductor's initial current is zero? Fixed values.. what do you mean? How can I check and see the initial values set by the LTspice if I don't skip the initial point operation ?

Comment: Are " initial operating point solution" and "DC operating point" same things?

Comment: @newage2000 You need to buy a book, I think. I'd recommend The Spice Book by Andrei Vladimirescu. If you skip things (use UIC) then all inductor currents start at zero and all capacitor voltages start at zero, except for any .IC Spice commands you might add. If you don't skip this first step (let it go "normally") then Spice will pre-compute them before starting the run. Go back to your first circuit without the UIC added, use 10 mH or 1 mH, instead. Notice any difference in current? The value of the inductor doesn't matter, does it? Now try the same with UIC added. You will see value matters.

Answer (score 0):

> Why infinite voltage would be needed for a sudden change?

'Sudden' means that T is very very small, almost zero. So, the only way to produce finite value of integral - to get very very large (almost infinite) 'v'.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a step current ( shutoff) of inductor current causes an impulse voltage the same is true in reverse...

- A slew rate limited V pulse will result in a slew rate limited step current according to the integral.
- Thus a step current with 0 rise time is impossible.  ( this assumes you understand basic calculus and definition of an infinite impulse.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function (the Dirac delta) adjusted over smaller and smaller times. All the variations integrate to 1. Graphic is taken from and more information is available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

[image]

The area under each of the curves must be 1.0, so as the time gets smaller and smaller the height of the curve must get taller and taller.

Integrated, each of the curves will be step of +1.0 from the initial value (perhaps zero), so it represents the amount of voltage you would have to apply to get an ideal 1H inductor to conduct 1A over a certain period of time.

An ideal inductor would continue to conduct the same currrent after the voltage falls back to zero, but real (room temperature) inductors have some resistance so the current fairly rapidly falls back towards zero when you short them.