# Inductors - understanding the depth of its working

Tags: inductor

When there is an initial change in current, I understand that the inductor resists the change. but how does it eventually give in with the flow of current?
can someone give me the nuances of the working of the inductor?

Comment: Do the answers in [How does an inductor store energy?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161457/how-does-an-inductor-store-energy) help in understanding the working of an inductor?

Comment: it takes time for a magnetic field to change

Comment: There can be no *initial change in current* <-- not without infinite voltage being required or produced. An inductor doesn't give in either; it does what it does very consistently.

Comment: If it does what it does, then why the current flow? eventually doesn't it conduct the current after the inductor is fully charge like a normal conductor?

Comment: If we're talking ideal inductors then an inductor never can get fully charged; it will always continue charging when an ideal DC voltage source is applied to its terminals.

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you have described. I agree that you might be right, but can you give me some perspective as to how an ideal inductor behaves. I need it to study the power electronic converters, rectifiers, which uses inductors, inductors are everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inductor acts against a change in current. For an ideal step change, i.e. a forcible change of current in no time, the resulting voltage is infinite.

\$V = L \cdot \frac{\Delta I}{\Delta t}  \qquad[Volt;Henry;\frac{Amper}{second}]\$

For a finite slope of current over time, you get a finite voltage.

Comment: An L is missing.

Comment: I understand that. thanks. But the how the inductor's resistance to block the current is overpowered until di/dt becomes zero, is what I want to understand

Comment: @Fredrick You need to start from specifying what is given, and what results. Is the slope of current given, and voltage results? Or, is voltage applied to the coil, and the current slope results? To me, the latter way is easier to understand. Voltage is like "pressure" (a mechanical force) and inductance is like inertia. Have you ever tried to push a heavy loaded cart on flat surface? Or a small merry-go-round with children sitting on it? You apply a mechanical force, and it gradually starts moving. The slope ends when you stop pushing. Stop applying mechanical force.

Comment: Since I am not solving any problem, I can't say what's given. I just want to  understand it from a fundamental and deep approach. Yes, that's a very good illustration. thanks